# How to add registration form in popup box in magento?

Tags: magento, popup

I am new in `magento`. I want to open registration page in popup box. Is there any module/way available to do so? 
After a long research found some of extension but no solution.

For the custom code Popup already set. Want to add registration form only.

Please help.

Thank you!

Comment: Ajax iogin https://magecomp.com/magento-mobile-login.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long research found a perfect solution.

Steps :

1. Install [Ajax Popup For Login & Registration](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-popup-for-login-registration.html) extension
2. This extension adds the possibility for users to log in / register via an ajax popup.
3. Now set that popup on page load (only for homepage).
   Just add below script in `CMS > Pages > Your homepage block > Content`.

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ajaxlogin-login")[0].click();
});
```

4. Save Page.. and that's it.

Hope it will helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do in custom and easy way without the module

create a new phtml file for registration like : customer/form/register_popup.phtml

inside the div that you want as a popup

but this lines

getLayout()->createBlock('customer/form_register')->setTemplate('customer/form/register_popup.phtml'); ?>

and enjoy ):

Comment: Thank you for your help. But customer/form/ folder not found in my magento.

Comment: How to add registration form?

Comment: you can find the file in the base -> default theme of magento and then copy the register.phtml to register_popup.phtml and try my code that should work